# Anti Markovnikov Product with Oxymercuration - Demercuration

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

Consider the Oxymercuration - Demercuration of the following compound with $\ce{Hg(OAc)2}$ followed by treatment with $\ce{NaBH4}$ in basic medium:
[image]

Here, if we go according to Markovnikov addition of water to the double bond, the $\ce{OH}$ group should get attached the carbon having the 2 methyl groups

But if go by the mechanism, we find that a more stable intermediate is formed when the partial positive charge lies on the carbon having the phenyl group as a benzyl carbocation is considered to be more stable than a secondary carbocation and thus we could very well expect an $\ce{OH}$ group on the carbon having the phenyl group.

So which one would be the major product in this case - The Markovnikov or Anti-Markovnikov product?

Comment: In my textbook, Organic chemistry by david klein it's said that the mercunium ion intemrediate involves a three memberd ring w/ resonance. This lead me to prefer benzylic position but I asked some of my friends doing o chem degrees and they told this wans't standard.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does water attack the more substituted carbon in oxymercuration?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/86341/why-does-water-attack-the-more-substituted-carbon-in-oxymercuration)